# iPhone – Photoshop like effects

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

Can I make in iphone multiply, screen, color or other photoshop like effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/index.html)

Focus on Blending Demo ;)

Comment: Hi there,
Is it possible to blend two images like they show in Quartz/QuartzBlending.m? and not rwo rects filled with solid colour?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to replicate many of the Photoshop functions in iOS in a project here: https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters