# Replicate Photoshop "Multiply effects"

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, imagemagick, photoshop

how can i replicate a Photoshop "Multiply effects" with Image Magick library or obj-c code for iphone?
Where can i found some example code of this?
I have see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784020/iphone-photoshop-like-effects)

Answer (score 8):

If you want an easy way to do this, my [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework has its GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter, which takes in two images and performs a red, green, blue, and alpha channel-by-channel multiplication for each pixel. It does so in a GPU-accelerated manner, so it can be 4-6X faster than performing the same operations on the CPU.

To use this, set up your two images to blend:

```
UIImage *inputImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];    
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage1];

UIImage *inputImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"];    
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage2];
```

then create and configure your blend filter:

```
GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[inputImage1 processImage];
[inputImage1 addTarget:blendFilter];
[inputImage2 addTarget:blendFilter];
[inputImage2 processImage];
```

and finally extract the blended image result:

```
UIImage *filteredImage = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

One caveat with this in its current implementation is that devices older than the iPad 2 have limited texture sizes, so images larger than 2048x2048 can't be processed on these older devices right now. I'm working on fixing that.

Comment: Brad Larson great answer! :) but can you also apply tint using the library?

Comment: @janusfidel - There are several different ways of altering the color content of an image, from adjusting the exposure, gain, or brightness, to shifting the values in one of the color components and applying a color matrix. The latter is used in one case to perform a sepia tone adjustment to the image. Beyond that, it's easy to write new filters with just a small amount of C-like code to do just the effect you want.

Comment: @BradLarson : I am doing same thing as above but I am unable to find `imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` method for my blendFilter. Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: @Devang - That method has been replaced recently. Read the last section of this for what you need to do now: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/03/17/switching-gpuimage-use-cached-framebuffers

Answer (score 4):

Multiply is a (what Adobe calls) blend mode. Blend modes are essentially pixel operations using some mathematical formula. You can blend two images together, or you can use one, resulting in a 'self-blend'.

This can be achieved by doing operations on your image pixel by pixel, by getting each channel value for the specific pixel and working on it.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the Magick library. However, here is a formula which, given a channel value (red, green or blue, 0 - 255) would return the resulting value of a multiply operation.

`unsigned char result = a * b / 255;`

Note here, a and b must also be unsigned chars, else overflow might occur because the result would be larger than one byte. This is the basic multiply formula, you can adapt the variables to support 16-bits per channel by assigning larger variable sizes and modifying the divisor appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing Brad Larson code it worked fine for me.

```
UIImage *inputImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage1];

UIImage *inputImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.jpg"];
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage2];

GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[stillImageSource1 processImage];
[stillImageSource1 addTarget:blendFilter];
[stillImageSource2 addTarget:blendFilter];
[stillImageSource2 processImage];

[blendFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

UIImage *filteredImage = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

[self.imageView setImage:filteredImage];
```